# How to set default XAML view in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: xaml, view, visual-studio-2008, designer

In Visual Studio 2008, when you add a new XAML window to a WPF Application Project, the default view you get is "split view" where the visual designer and the XAML code are shown one above the other in the same document.

I prefer an alternative view which you can get by double-clicking on either the Design or XAML tabs. The visual designer and the XAML are in separate side-by-side tabbed views. This makes it easy to switch between them

I want to know if it possible to make this the default view for all new XAML documents I add to my project, and where in the options you would set it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tools/Options/Text Editor/Xaml/Miscellaneous, check the "Always open documents in full XAML view"

Comment: Brilliant - I knew someone on SO would know!

Comment: I have found that the more complex my WPF projects get, the more unstable the design view becomes -- it becomes essential to turn off the design view in order to get the pages to load at all and to keep them from crashing studio.  I'm hopeful and confident that VS 2010 will fix this.

Comment: I haven't seen VS2010 *crash* from the visual editor, but it's very slow on my laptop and this option makes everything happy again. You rock!

Comment: The design mode seems to cause even more crashes when using TFS for source control. In a sufficiently complex application, it pretty much crashes every time I try to add a new usercontrol/window/page. Bleh.