# Visual Studio 2012 sometimes switches me into Design view (from XAML view)

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, designer

I have Visual Studio set up to put me in [XAML Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334717/how-to-set-default-xaml-view-in-visual-studio-2008), and use that almost exclusively. However, I'm finding that sometimes - usually just after I create a new element, put a blank line in it, and then save (but it doesn't appear to be consistent) it suddenly and jarringly switches me into Design mode.

I never noticed this happening in the release candidate.

Any ideas why this might be happening, and how I can stop it from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem as you, when I set a new property it switched to Design view and hanged the entire Visual Studio.

Usually I take the following steps to find the issue:

1. Did you install a plugin/extension which caused this?
   If yes, then uninstall or disable it to see if it solves the problem.
2. Try starting it in `safemode`: See this [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
3. Start Visual Studio and `log` all activity: See how to do it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
4. Repair Visual Studio.

In my case, the issue was related to a component (Intersoft to be exactly).

Comment: You can use markdown to format your answer for clarity, including the regular naming of links, etc.  This is the kind of quality of writing that I believe SO is looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do it in future posts.